# find the divs which do not have style display none and insert a style for page break on every second div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initially all divs are having style display none property. I am enabling the divs by jquery show method if there is any content inside them,
I want to find the divs which do not have style display:none, and after every second active div,
I want to insert a css for page-break-after:always for print purpose. I want to have only 2 divs in one page when user prints.
so in this example, I want to insert css for page break on par4, and par8

(so in short find the divs which do not have style display none and insert a style for page break on every second div)

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="flip" id="par1" style="display:none;">empty</div>                     
<div class="flip" id="par2">Image/content</div>                           
<div class="flip" id="par3" style="display:none;">empty</div>                       
<div class="flip" id="par4">Image/content</div>                            
<div class="flip" id="par5" style="display:none;">empty</div>                        
<div class="flip" id="par6">Image/content</div>                         
<div class="flip" id="par7" style="display:none;">empty</div>                             
<div class="flip" id="par8">Image/content</div>                                             
<div class="flip" id="par10" style="display:none;">empty</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Should be UL/LI, instead of DIV/DIV.

Comment: Have you tried 'anything' besides the HTML here?

Comment: Show us your code that "*enables the divs by jQuery show if there is any content*" (to me the string "empty" would also be content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
$( '#parent' ).children( ':visible:odd' ).css( 'page-break-after', 'always' );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/KxGKG/2/

Although I recommend setting a CSS class, instead of writing the style inline. It is easier to set/unset classes, than styles directly.

Comment: @undefined OP didn't specify that visible DIVs are always even children.

Comment: Yes, but what about jQuery collection?

Comment: @undefined Ah, you're right. `:odd` selects in regard to the jQuery selection, and not the actual DOM relationship. May I update my answer with that improvement?

Comment: Thanks! bang on target! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you, but isn't CSS a better solution for that?

```
$(function() {
    $(".flip:nth-child(even)").css({ 'page-break-after': 'always' });
});
```

Comment: OP didn't specify that visible DIVs are always even children.

Comment: Ok so, how about $(".flip:visible:nth-child(even)")? Shouldn't that filter out the invisible elements before choosing every second (even) one?

Comment: No. `:nth-child` still takes the DOM relationship into account. So, an even child is always an even child, regardless of its position in the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery :visible selector with an each loop will do the trick.

```
$('.flip:visible').each(function(idx, elm) {
    if(idx & 1 == 1) { // every 2nd one
        $(this).css('page-break-after', 'always');
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
The nth (even) select is more elegant (and shorted code).

Comment: `if (idx & 1 == 1 )`? really?

Comment: @undefined Well, then it's JavaScript. `i & 1` returns `0` or `1`, depending on whether `i` is even or odd. Nice.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yes, I didn't know that, Nice.